# Parachute deployment using DJI Onboard SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm researching whether it's possible to detect an emergency situation using OSDK to automatically deploy a parachute with an On Board Computer. Please see [this block diagram of my setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ytN.png) for clarity.

We're using the DJI N3 flight controller. **In order to deploy a parachute we need to make sure that the rotors are stopped to avoid nasty and dangerous entanglements**.

**What I've tried:**

I've been trying to figure out when the N3 does stop the motors to trigger the parachute at that point, and found that it will happen in these two situations:

1. Manually disarming the drone (no matter if the aircraft is on ground or flying)
2. If it's flying and an extreme roll angle is applied to it

In both cases, the broadcast data "Flight Status" has its 'flight' field set to 0 (STOPPED).

Therefore I've assumed that the natural Flight Status transitions are:
0 (STOPPED) -----[Arm]-----> 1 (ON_GROUND) -----[takeoff]----> 2 (IN_AIR) ----[land]---> 1 (ON_GROUND) -----[Disarm]----> 0 (STOPPED)

Following up with this assumption I have programmed the OBC to detect direct transitions from 2 (IN_AIR) to 0 (STOPPED) without going through 1(ON_GROUND).

The result is (almost) as expected: When the N3 disarms in flight due to an abnormal situation, the motors are stopped and the parachute is deployed. This can also be done manually by the pilot by doing the corresponding CSC.

However, **the problem** we're finding with this solution is that most of the times, upon normal landing, the Flight Status 'status' field directly transitions from 2 (flying) to 0 (stopped) tricking the OBC into thinking the parachute needs to be deployed. Please see the [Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoaFq.png), which is an excerpt from the flight log data as plotted by DJI's data viewer.

I believe that relying on the reported altitude is not a robust solution as we have been observing quite unreliable readings, so **my questions are:**

- Is there a better/more reliable solution?.
- Would using the intelligent gear signal to detect low altitude do any good here? (our landing gear is fixed)
- Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I was wrong, apparently it **does** go through ON_GROUND. [But just for a split millisecond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzHET.png). The controller spends only 0.02 s in the ON_GROUND state. Given that my broadcast rate is 50 Hz for Flight Status, that would have been easily missed by the OBC. I'll try increasing the broadcast rate up to 100 Hz.

EDIT 2:

The newly released OSDK 3.7 seems to provide a way of detecting abnormal situations in-flight and does provide a new API to stop the motors when airborne... I'll give these a try.

Answer (score 1):

The way I implemented the Parachute deployment with OSDK is sth different than you

## Software

First I have set of sensors on board the drone which included IDS 1221 camera/ vector Nav IMU and a 3D LIDAR.

In the backend, I`m estimating the visual-lidar-inertial based odometry/state estimation with the sensor and control inputs.

If drone position output has too much difference(state estimation variance large than a threshold) with the input control for more than N secs.

It means that drone is not holding it position/velocity command and therefore being considered as a rogue and should be killed.

## Hardware

In the hardware part, I have the following connection set up

Power in ->  A3 -> Motor cut Relay -> ESC -> Motor

Power in ->  NUC + additional sensors ->  PWM ->Motor cut Relay

Power in ->  NUC -> PWM -> chute

The NUC controls the relay by PWM. Once detects the large variances, perform motor power cut and deploy chute